# Ampersand is reading in as & amp; in R, using read.xlsx?

Tags: r, openxlsx, readxl

I'm reading in a .xlsx file using **read.xlsx** to R. The data contains rows which have **ampersands (&)** in them. This is reading in as " & amp;" in my data when I use read.xlsx. Does anyone know if there's a way to stop this?

PS. I previously wrote out the file using write_xlsx, then read it back in using read.xlsx.

Comment: I'm now looking into this now and I'm surprised an obvious fix isn't proposed

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using `read_excel` from the readxl package!